# node js incoming request sourceIP

Tags: node.js

For example:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   request.on("end", function () {

   });
});
```

Using [Request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request), how I can I find the source IP of the request?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
var http = require('http');

var getClientIp = function(req) {
  var ipAddress = null;
  var forwardedIpsStr = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
  if (forwardedIpsStr) {
    ipAddress = forwardedIpsStr[0];
  }
  if (!ipAddress) {
    ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  }
  return ipAddress;
};

var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
  console.log(getClientIp(req));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  return res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(9000, 'localhost');
```

the `getClientIp` function was taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/1626318) with some minor changes. Note that the contents of `x-forwarded-for` is an array containing proxy IPs, (read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)), so you may wish to inspect more than the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether the request is made by a proxy forward or direct connection the source ip address may be stored at different places. You have to check `req.header['x-forwarded-for']` first and then `req.connection.remoteAddress`. An example function is shown in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1626318).